# Retrieve accounts balance in stripe not working

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve the balance for a connected account. The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_retrieve?lang=node) says to do the following:

```
stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

The problem is that it's retrieving the entire stripes balance, not the connected accounts balance. How can I retrieve a specific connected accounts balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the balance of a connected account you need to specify the connected account's id when making the request as follows [0]:

```
  stripe.balance
    .retrieve({ stripeAccount: "acct_xyz" })
    .then(function(balance) {
      console.log(balance);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

Note that you will need to replace "acct_xyz" with your connected account ID.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts